# How to reduce code redundancy in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am coding an app in Swift that involves populating a table based by iterating through information from arrays that are appended after a database query. I have the query, the appending, and the `tableView.reloadData()` all in the `viewDidLoad()` method. It works fine. I also have nearly the exact same code written into a refresh function that responds with a pull on the screen. It also works well. The problem, however, is that it's very busy. There's alot of code written twice and I am wondering what is the best way to fix that. Here is the relevant code:

in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad(){
//run query, append arrays
self.tableView.reloadData()
}refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DisplayEventsTVC.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}
```

The refresh function:

```
    func refresh(sender: AnyObject){{
    //exact same query and appending
}
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
```

The query and appending is very long, so I would like a better way to handle that than simply copy and pasting the code from the viewdidload() into the refresh function and adding an .endRefreshing(). What is the best/most efficient way to do this?

This is all done in a tableviewcontroller.

Comment: So why isn't the "query and appending" just off in a separate func that `viewDidLoad` and `refresh` both call? It looks like this func would need to also provide a completion handler, so you can control the timing of `endRefreshing`. Assuming "query and appending" is done in a separate thread, `viewDidLoad` will need `tableView.reloadData()` too.

Comment: @Michael, sorry yes. The viewDidLoad does have a .reloadData(), I forgot to put it in the question. What is the best way to set up the completion handler for refresh... not too good with that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In Protocol oriented way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, Refreshable {
    var refreshTitle: String = "Pull to refresh"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        queryAndAppend(completion: {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        self.setupRefresh()//I don't want to name it
    }
}

//Somewhere else 
protocol Refreshable {
  var refreshTitle: String {get}
  var tableView: UITableView 
  var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl
}

extension Refreshable where Self: UIViewController {
func setupRefresh(){
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DisplayEventsTVC.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

//copying from @Michael ans
func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    queryAndAppend(completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    })
}

func queryAndAppend(completion completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    // your existing code goes here
    if let completion = completion {
        completion()
    }
}

}
```

Just a draft snippet, not tested

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in my comment, pull the common code out into a separate func that has a completion handler. I'm thinking something along the lines of...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    queryAndAppend(completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DisplayEventsTVC.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    queryAndAppend(completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    })
}

func queryAndAppend(completion completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    // your existing code goes here
    if let completion = completion {
        completion()
    }
}
```